# How do I find the second, or third instance of a character in a string in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to parse out the middle of the referrer information just to check from where the form submission is coming from.

Consider that the referrer is "https://www.somewebsite.com/someform.php
And what I want to extract is the part between those first two "//" and the next one "/".

I can get the string position, but how can I do a quick piece of code that will just parse out the part I need without several steps?

$ref=strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'://');
gives me 5 (as the position where the "://" is found.

I want to use something like substr(string,start,length) the part out that is needed to get the pure referrer

the part that says "**www.somewebsite.com**"

without all the extra lines of code

Comment: do you want to grab the hostname name only?

Comment: the answer below nailed it. basically it's to prevent a mailman script from being used unless the submission came from inside the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used it

`echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

Comment: That was fast. Thank you, it's implemented and works perfect.